# Creating UIImage from context of UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

So I am cropping an image with a UIImageView which may or may not be very efficient.  I'm some what a n00b when it comes to Graphics programming.  When all my code runs I am stuck with a white image and I'm not quite sure why.

I took a look at this: [Crop and save visible region of UIImageView using AspectFill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604559/crop-and-save-visible-region-of-uiimageview-using-aspectfill) and have had no success.  Here is my code:

```
imageFile = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

selectedImage.hidden = false;  //selectedImage is my UIImageView
selectedImage.image = imageFile;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(selectedImage.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

float width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
float height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

CGImageRef cropped_img = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));

imageFile = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropped_img];
imageFile = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile, 0.05f)];

selectedImage.image = imageFile;  //Final product is white
```

So `selectedImage` is my `UIImageView` and that is what ends up being white.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from this SO post: [Creating UIImage from context of UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807693/creating-uiimage-from-context-of-uiimageview)

Here's the solution:

I needed to import the Quartz Core Framework: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Then I used the following method:

```
- (UIImage*)imageFromImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, 2*M_PI);

    [imageView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *image =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line?

```
imageFile = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile, 0.05f)];
```

If you are getting a UIImage from the line directly above it I would not think you would then need to pass it through at an extremely low JPEG compression rate.  0 being the lowest quality, maybe it's so low it looks white.  Try removing that line and or changing the compression.

Comment: That didn't work and the compression is not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In these lines

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

you create a new context, that will be blank (white) and then create an image from this. So your resulting image will just be white.

The function `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` needs a `CGImageRef`, which you can get from a `UIImage` easily with

```
CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageFile.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
```

---

Not sure why you are doing this line

```
imageFile = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile, 0.05f)];
```

This will just give you a poor quality image :/

Comment: So should I replace those first two lines with the third line you gave me?  I'm trying to get the visible image of the imageView.  The part that is cropped.  I understand what you are talking about with the new context stuff.  Maybe I should read the docs ;)  I got the `0.05f` from a parse tutorial.  Maybe I should go with `0.5`?  I just don't want upload times to be long and to use a lot of data for the end user.

Comment: That sounds about right. You should def compress when you upload, I thought this was just put into an imageView therefore compressing would have been weird.

Comment: Can I start a chat.  I didn't quite get the results I was expecting.

Comment: I'm on an iPad so can't chat. You will need to handle screen scale manually with that function. E.g. `width * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale` and the same for height. What issue are you seeing?

Comment: That code crops my UIImage but I want to create an image from the context of the UIImageView including how the image is being cropped.  So when I have an image in the imageView and use aspect fill, I want to create an image from that filled view.