# Cropping visible part of UIImage in UIImageView for saliency

Tags: swift, uiimageview, crop, vision

I'm doing attentionBased saliency and should pass image to the request. When the contentMode is ScaleAspectFill, the result of the request is not correct, because I use full image (not visible on screen part)

I'm trying to crop UIImage, but this method doesn't crop correctly

```
 let newImage = cropImage(imageToCrop: imageView.image, toRect: imageView.frame)


 func cropImage(imageToCrop: UIImage?, toRect rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageRef = imageToCrop?.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect) else {
            return nil
        }
        let cropped: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
        return cropped
    }
```

How can I make saliency request only for the visible part of the image (which changes when change contentMode)?

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do... Do you have a `UIImage` that is not the same aspect-ratio as your `UIImageView`, so part of it is not visible with `ScaleAspectFill` -- and you want to create a **new** `UIImage` based on the visible portion?

Comment: No. I have UIImageView with ScaleAspectFill and not full image is visible with this contentMode, so probably I should use only visible part of the image for saliency request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crop and save visible region of UIImageView using AspectFill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604559/crop-and-save-visible-region-of-uiimageview-using-aspectfill)

Comment: Besides the above solution, you can also do the opposite: knowing the size of the frame in which image will be displayed, cut the image prior to displaying it to frame proportions and use aspectFit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly...

Suppose we have this `640 x 360` image:

[image]

and we display it in a `240 x 240` image view, using `.scaleAspectFill`...

It looks like this (the red outline is the image view frame):

[image]

and, with `.clipsToBounds = true`:

[image]

we want to generate this **new** `360 x 360` image (that is, we want to keep the **original** image resolution... we don't want to end up with a `240 x 240` image):

[image]

To crop the visible portion of the image, we need to calculate the scaled rect, including the offset:

```
func cropImage(imageToCrop: UIImage?, toRect rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageRef = imageToCrop?.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect) else {
        return nil
    }
    let cropped: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
    return cropped
}

func myCrop(imgView: UIImageView) -> UIImage? {
    
    // get the image from the imageView
    guard let img = imgView.image else { return nil }
    
    // image view rect
    let vr: CGRect = imgView.bounds
    
    // image size -- we need to account for scale
    let imgSZ: CGSize = CGSize(width: img.size.width * img.scale, height: img.size.height * img.scale)
    
    let viewRatio: CGFloat = vr.width / vr.height
    let imgRatio: CGFloat = imgSZ.width / imgSZ.height
    
    var newRect: CGRect = .zero
    
    // calculate the rect that needs to be clipped from the full image
    
    if viewRatio > imgRatio {
        
        // image has a wider aspect ratio than the image view
        //  so top and bottom will be clipped
        let f: CGFloat = imgSZ.width / vr.width
        let h: CGFloat = vr.height * f
        newRect.origin.y = (imgSZ.height - h) * 0.5
        newRect.size.width = imgSZ.width
        newRect.size.height = h
        
    } else {
        
        // image has a narrower aspect ratio than the image view
        //  so left and right will be clipped
        let f: CGFloat = imgSZ.height / vr.height
        let w: CGFloat = vr.width * f
        newRect.origin.x = (imgSZ.width - w) * 0.5
        newRect.size.width = w
        newRect.size.height = imgSZ.height
        
    }
    
    return cropImage(imageToCrop: img, toRect: newRect)
}
```

and call it like this:

```
if let croppedImage = myCrop(imgView: theImageView) {
    // do something with the new image
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I wanted to achieve! Thank you! You saved me

Comment: @Karina - if this answered your question, be sure to mark it as "Accepted" for the benefit of other users who may come across it.